# Issue with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a slider in which the slides or coming from ajax.
In which hovering over the slider div stops the slider. 
For that I have created a function sliderPopulateBlocks() which makes a call to the service page 
takes the slides put them in the container the called the function to move slides for that I have
used a function moveItems() which is called on an interval using setInterval().

Problem is with stopping the slides on hover of div, I am clearing the interval using clearInterval(). 
It works fine when called first on document ready.
But when called the same function on category click then after second click slider not stopping on hover.

```
<script>
var interval_two;
function sliderPopulateBlocks(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"service.php",
        data:{t:"slider"},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data,status){
            if(status == "success"){
                if(data.status == "ok"){                    
                    var data_arr = data.details;
                    var final_html = '';
                    $.each(data_arr, function(index,value){
                        var returned_html = '<div class="popular-column"></div>';
                        final_html = final_html + returned_html;
                    });
                    var container = $("#popular-two");
                    container.html(final_html);
                } else {

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            //show the error
        },
        complete: function(){           
            if( total_slides_two > max_item ){
                moveItems("#popular-two");
                interval_two = setInterval(function(){moveItems("#popular-two")}, 5000);                
                $(".popular-two").mouseover(function(){
                    clearInterval(interval_two);
                });
                $(".popular-two").mouseleave(function(){
                    interval_two = setInterval(function(){moveItems("#popular-two")}, 5000);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    sliderPopulateBlocks();
    $(".category-list ul li").click(function(){
        sliderPopulateBlocks();
    });
});
</script>

<!-- html -->
<div class="scroll-div popular-one">
    <a id="prev-popular-one" href="javascript:void(0);" class="previous-bt">Previous</a>
    <a id="next-popular-one" href="javascript:void(0);" class="next-bt">Next</a>
    <div class="scroll-con">
        <div class="popular-details" id="popular-one">  <!--popular-details start-->



        </div>  <!--popular-details end-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval()` returns the ID of the created interval. `clearInterval()` clears the interval with the ID you pass to it.

What probably happens is that more that one intervals are set, but `interval_two` will only hold the ID from the last interval, which means that all other intervals will continue to run.

Instead of saving `interval_two = setInterval()` add the ID to an array:

```
var interval_two = [];

interval_two.push(setInterval());
```

And then clear the intervals in a loop:

```
function clearIntervals(interval_two) {
    for(var i = 0, len = interval_two.length; i < len; i++) {
        clearInterval(interval_two[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are adding content dynamically using `ajax` use `on` and bind the `events` in document `ready` and not in ajax call as below:

```
interval_two = interval_two = setInterval(function() {
    moveItems("#popular-two");
}, 5000);

$('"#popular-two"').on('mouseenter', '.popular-two', function() {
    clearInterval(interval_two);
}).on('mouseleave', '.popular-two', function() {
    interval_two = setInterval(function() {
        moveItems("#popular-two");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the AJAX is called, you're adding a new `mouseover` event handler onto `.popular-two`. This means that the first time it's run, there's one, the second time, there are two, etc.

This will have the effect of creating multiple intervals, with only the most recently created one being stored as `interval_two`.

You can fix this by moving the `mouseover` and `mouseout` outside of the AJAX call.

```
var interval_two
function sliderPopulateBlocks(){
  $.ajax({
      // code not relevant to the answer omitted here
      complete: function(){           
          if( total_slides_two > max_item ){
              moveItems("#popular-two");
              interval_two = setInterval(function(){moveItems("#popular-two")}, 5000);                
          }
      }
  });
}

// move event handlers outside of AJAX to ensure they only get assigned once. 
$(".popular-two").mouseover(function(){
  clearInterval(interval_two);
});
$(".popular-two").mouseleave(function(){
  interval_two = setInterval(function(){moveItems("#popular-two")}, 5000);
});
```